# unable to deploy war file in jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am new to jboss-AS. I am trying to deploy a war file in deployments directory, but I am getting war file renamed with .failed name.
say xxx.war is kept in deployments dir,the new file is also found after some time with www.war.failed.
content of failed war file are as below:
cat xxx-1.1.war.failed

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\": JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}[rhino@Rhino deployments
```

i tried everything to troubleshoot it with the help of google with NO success !!
i tried with fresh war files still not worked.

I am kind of stuck with this for the last one week..
Please help!!
Thanks..

**Server.log as below:**

```
00:47:41,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "xxx-1.1.war"
00:47:44,436 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) loading config....
00:47:44,445 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (claroLogger).
00:47:44,445 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
00:47:44,484 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxx-1.1]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error configuring application listener of class com.nsn.claroUI.util.ClaroUIContextListener: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3342) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nsn.claroUI.util.ClaroUIContextListener.<clinit>(ClaroUIContextListener.java:74) [classes:]
        ... 28 more
00:47:44,514 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxx-1.1]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
00:47:44,515 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
00:47:44,519 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/xxx-1.1] startup failed due to previous errors
00:47:44,523 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/xxx-1.1": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/xxx-1.1": JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
00:47:44,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
00:47:44,535 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 7351ms - Started 478 of 557 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
00:47:44,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "xxx-1.1.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\": JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
00:47:44,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment xxx-1.1.war in 251ms
00:47:44,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/xxx-1.1": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/xxx-1.1": JBAS018040: Failed to start context
00:47:44,996 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/xxx-1.1\": JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

Comment: Try and build and then deploy this example and see if it works for you.  Also, can you update your question with your web.xml? [Example](https://github.com/doct15/example-tomcat-war)

Comment: but it is a working war file i fetched from production node.

Comment: Then I'd imagine the production node is running a newer or older version of JBoss than what you have locally, or is setup differently, for example it might be running in "full" or "HA" mode and you might be starting JBoss with nether of those.  Easiest thing to always do if you can is to make a tar and zip file of the production JBoss folder and copy it to your local machine and start it in the same way it is being started on the server.  If you're a little hesitant to touch production you might see if theres someone a little more comfortable doing what I mentioned.

Comment: Other option is to download same version that production is using to your local dev box, make sure you're configuration file has same settings as production and start it in the same way.  If you need help with troubleshooting all that, let me know what operating system the production node is running and the path to the JBoss installation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the stack trace of the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nsn.claroUI.util.ClaroUIContextListener.<clinit>(ClaroUIContextListener.java:74) [classes:]
    ... 28 more
```

You need to see what's at line 74 of `com.nsn.claroUI.util.ClaroUIContextListener`.